# Code Contracts: Why are some invariants not considered outside the class?

Tags: c#, .net, static-analysis, code-contracts, design-by-contract

Consider this immutable type:

```
public class Settings
{
    public string Path { get; private set; }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void ObjectInvariants()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(Path != null);
    }

    public Settings(string path)
    {
        Contract.Requires(path != null);
        Path = path;
    }
}
```

Two things to notice here:

- There is a contract invariant which ensures the `Path` property can never be `null`
- The constructor checks the `path` argument value to respect the previous contract invariant

At this point, a `Setting` instance can never have a `null` `Path` property.

Now, look at this type:

```
public class Program
{
    private readonly string _path;

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void ObjectInvariants()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(_path != null);
    }

    public Program(Settings settings)
    {
        Contract.Requires(settings != null);
        _path = settings.Path;
    } // <------ "CodeContracts: invariant unproven: _path != null"
}
```

Basically, it has its own contract invariant (on `_path` field) that can't be satisfied during static checking (cf. comment above). That sounds a bit weird to me, since it's easy to prove it:

- `settings` is immutable
- `settings.Path` can't be null (because Settings has the corresponding contract invariant)
- so by assigning `settings.Path` to `_path`, `_path` can't be null

Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 10):

After checking the [code contracts forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/codecontracts), I found [this similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/b84a414e-e4aa-4586-847f-83379457d322) with the following answer from one of the developers:

> I think the behavior you are experiencing is caused by some inter-method inference that is going on. The static checker first analyzes the constructors, then the properties and then the methods. When analyzing the constructor of Sample, it does not know that msgContainer.Something != null so it issues the warning. A way to solve it, is either by adding an assumption  msgContainer.Something != null in the constuctor, or better to add the postcondition != null to Something.

So in other words, your options are:

1. Make the `Settings.Path` property explicit instead of automatic, and specify the invariant on the backing field instead. In order to satisfy your invariant, you will need to add a precondition to the property's set accessor: `Contract.Requires(value != null)`.

   You can optionally add a postcondition to the get accessor with `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null)`, but the static checker will not complain either way.
2. Add `Contract.Assume(settings.Path != null)` to the constructor of the `Program` class.

Answer (score 0):

Invariants don't work on private members, you cannot actually have the reason why it is this way, hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, they do. Otherwise invariants would be of very little help.